# Spring LiveReload and Devtools without Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, devtools, livereload

Is it possible to use Spring devtools and Livereload with Spring4 without using actual Spring Boot?

I am working on a legacy Spring 4 project and having it would save a lot of time.
I am used to these features from Spring 5 Boot.

Many thanks
Vito

Comment: did you get a solution ? I am also trouble finding that solution. Could you please help me out the answer for your question.

Comment: No, I am back to Spring Boot 5 :).